# Error while running Jetty server with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, jetty, java-ee-6, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using m2eclipse.

I configured jetty-maven plugin in pom.xml properly.

when I try to execute through CMD its working fine. No error

Whereas when I try to execute through eclipse,

```
$    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava/compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspended=y,address=8000
Exception in thread "main"      $
```

I am missing some Jetty - Eclipse configuration. Can someone suggest on this.

D0 you find any error in this,

> MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx512M -Xdebug 
>   -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y"

Comment: How are you executing it through `cmd`, and how are you executing it through Eclipse? Looks like you've mixed up the command and its parameters.

Comment: you can take a look at webby as well, it is a eclipse plugin that leverages the pom configuration to provide more of a standard eclipse experience. https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Maven+WAR+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I found it.... the mistake is in VM arguments.. If ur VM arguments is misspelled or something, it throws filenotfound error.

MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx512M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y"

Actual:

-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx512M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y

No MAVEN_OPTS no quotation in VM arguments while u enter in eclipse...